# How I could solve "Did not find four digit hex character" in Groovy?

Tags: regex, groovy

Im trying to do this command in groovy

but appears this error "Did not find four digit hex character"

```
  varinif="0066";
 varfinf="0075";
   string.replaceAll(/\n((?!(;29#:[\u${varinif}-\u${varfinf}]&)).)*(?=\n)/, '')
```

but when i do without variable works

```
 string.replaceAll(/\n((?!(;29#:[\u0066-\u0075]&)).)*(?=\n)/, '')
```

Please help me

Comment: what is the value of variable 'string'?

Comment: \u0066 to \u0075  in utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like `decodeHex()` to convert the hex string to raw bytes, possibly then needing to cast to a character type. Then you would interpolate the character directly into the character class without the `\u`.

```
string.replaceAll(/\n((?!(;29#:[${varinif}-${varfinf}]&)).)*(?=\n)/, '')
```

Basically, you're thinking of `\u` as a function that runs at runtime, but actually the compiler converts any instances of `\uXXXX` at compile-time. `\u${va` is clearly not a valid unicode character, so it never gets converted; your `\u` is left meaningless. That's why you need to use runtime methods to do the conversion.